# Type Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method newTab() from the type ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

This my code:

```
    ActionBar actionbar;
    actionbar=getActionBar();
    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionbar.addTab(ActionBar.newTab().setText("PHP").setTabListener(this)); //this line has Error in ActionBar.newTab()
```

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line of your code attempts to call a (static) method on the `ActionBar` class, whereas it should really be on an object instance.

Note the difference:

Incorrect:

```
actionbar.addTab(ActionBar.newTab().setText("PHP").setTabListener(this));
```

Correct:

```
actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText("PHP").setTabListener(this));
```